# In Sharepoint Workflow Forms how do I close form after clicking start or cancel

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

To be more clear, I am trying to modify the Form autogenerated by Sharepoint which you can see in Sharepoint Designer under Workflows -> Your Workflow -> Forms

[image]

By default you are given two buttons which is start and cancel which is self explainable, **Start** starts the workflow and **Cancel** does nothing.

[image]

Once I click on either of the buttons processing happens on the background but nothing interactive happens on the UI (I am expecting for it to go back on the sharepoint list and have a refreshed data or at least close the form).  How do I make it close the form?  The code behind for the buttons is

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-vb">
    <input type="button" value="Start" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__insert;__commit;__redirectsource;__redirectToList={',ddwrt:EcmaScriptEncode($ListName),'};'))}" />
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-vb" width="99%">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="btnCancel" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__cancel;__redirectsource;__redirectToList={',ddwrt:EcmaScriptEncode($ListName),'};'))}" />
</td>
```

Even theres a **`redirecttolist`** parameter on the built in javascript I does not redirect.  Any known workaround for this one? Or anything I am doing wrong?

**Edit - the first issue is now solved**

But I still have a slight problem as I dont know how to dynamically (not hard coded) pass TemplateID and ListID.  With ItemID I use {ItemId} that works fine.  To further illustrate what I mean see the screenshot and the comments below.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the page after it was auto generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing your workflow form ASPX page the `Source` URL parameter?

Ex: `.../MyWorflowPage.aspx?Source=http://sharepointserver/site/`

Comment: Looks like this will solve it, its heading to the right direction.  Now I have another problem, I made it work using your solution but I passed the querystrings manually, now How would I get the ListID and Template ID dynamically, like with the ItemID I use {ItemId} that works but if I use {ListID} and {TemplateID} it does not work, any ideas?

Comment: Raymund, where are you using {ItemID}, {ListID}, and {TemplateID} and why? Couldn't you just hard code these values into the links? (Sorry, this may be a dumb question since I don't have access to 2010)

Comment: Hi Kit, thanks for the response above, much appreciated.  Im using those becuase if I omit one then error occurs.  ItemID is for the Item itself which defines what item to run the workflow on, Template ID is the template ID of the workflow and List ID defines which list the item is in.  Right now I just hard coded it but I am asking if we can define it dynamically like how ItemID is working to be a bit elegant in the solution (you know what I mean).

Comment: I added a screenshot above for clarity

Comment: After much googling, I finally was able to find this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643%28office.12%29.aspx. However, the SharePoint 2010 version of that page doesn't include the URL tokens. Looks like you might be able to use {ListID} but I don't see any mention of {TemplateID}. I think you may just have to keep them hard coded...

Comment: +1 to Kit, that worked! Thanks a lot.  But I remember I did tried it earlier but did not worked (might be a typo)

Comment: One more to go I am done! I just need the Shrarepoint URL Token for Template ID's